# How to compare a char to [ in Julia?

Tags: string, file, julia, character, special-characters

In Julia, I have some lines in a file that start with a [ char. To get these lines, I try to compare the first char of each line to this char, but I seem to be missing some syntax. So far, I've tried this, which returns false (for the first one) or doesn't accept the char (for the second) :

`if (line[1] == "[")`

`if (line[1] == "\[")`

What would be the proper syntax to use here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You comparing a **string** `"["` not a  **char** `'['`

Hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 12):

The canonical way would be to use [`startswith`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.startswith), which works with both single characters and longer strings:

```
julia> line = "[hello, world]";

julia> startswith(line, '[') # single character
true

julia> startswith(line, "[") # length-1 string
true

julia> startswith(line, "[hello") # longer string
true
```

If you really want to get the first character of a string it is better to use [`first`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.first) since indexing to strings is, in general, tricky.

```
julia> first(line) == '['
true
```

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Unicode-and-UTF-8-1 for more details about string indexing.